# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment I have getting fatal error while installing cassandra

Tags: java, spring, maven, installation, cassandra

A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment I have getting fatal error while installing cassandra

```
 A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x0000000010014ed4, pid=9436, 
tid=0x0000000000000efc
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_261-b12) (build 1.8.0_261-b12)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.261-b12 mixed mode windows-amd64 compressed 
oops)
# Problematic frame:
# C  [sigar-amd64-winnt.dll+0x14ed4]
#
# Failed to write core dump. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of 
Windows
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# C:\Users\Win10\hs_err_pid9436.log
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
```

Comment: This appears to be Permission issue, could you please share hs_err_pid9436.log or check hs_err_pid9436.log any more details available.

Comment: Upgrade your JDK version to the most recent version of JDK8... https://adoptium.net/?variant=openjdk8&jvmVariant=hotspot

Answer (score 1):

Windows support was completely dropped in Cassandra 4.0 ([CASSANDRA-16171](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-16171)). There are several known issues with running Cassandra on Windows so support was limited even in earlier versions of Cassandra.

The recommended workarounds are:

- [Deploy Cassandra in Docker](https://cassandra.apache.org/_/quickstart.html)
- Deploy Cassandra in a VM using
  software like VirtualBox
- Deploy Cassandra in a Kubernetes cluster
  with [K8ssandra.io](https://k8ssandra.io/get-started/)

Otherwise if you just want to learn how to build apps on Cassandra, [Astra DB](https://dtsx.io/3jdZVbU) has a free tier and you can launch a cluster in 5 clicks. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

I had got the same problem. I solved that by downgrading the jdk-8u311 to the jdk-8u231.